# Transform feature with positive and negative values to all positive to feed into a CNN

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am looking to transform one feature which has positive and negative values into positive values only. The reason for this is that I want to use it as a layer of an RGB image, which only takes positive values.
The overall distribution of the values of this feature is normal. Any suggestions on how to modify the values to pass it correctly as RGB layers?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I ended up simply adding a scalar to the distributions to shift them to the right, making sure that the vast majority of the points lied within the positive axis.
Due to the nature of the data and the aim, I was only interested in the distribution of the points themselves, not the actual values (say -3, -1, 0 would be equivalent to 0, 2, 3 - the inital values +3). This is something to bear in mind before applying this method.